# The expected square of the determinant of a random row stochastic matrix

Tags: pr.probability, matrices, random-matrices, determinants, stochastic-matrices

In [this
question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256160) Anthony Quas asks about the expected absolute value of
the determinant of an $n\times n$ row stochastic matrix $A$, where
the rows are independently selected from the uniform distribution on
the unit $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex $x_1+\cdots+x_n=1$, $x_i\geq
0$. I can show by a messy computation that the integral over all such
matrices of $(\det A)^2$ is $1/(n+1)!^{n-1}$. Is there a
noncomputational reason for such a simple value?

Comment: Interesting. Is this the $(n-1)$st power of the factorial? This looks a lot smaller than I was expecting; or maybe I just misunderstood the random matrix result.

Comment: This is $(n+1)!$ to the $(n-1)$st power. However, this is not the average value of $(\det A)^2$. To get the average value one must divide by the volume, which is $1/(n-1)!^n$.

Comment: Great - so this gives the sort of size that I was expecting. Thanks for taking an interest in my original question.

Comment: @RichardStanley: that's not an answer to the "reason" question, but I think I see how to make a perhaps nicer computation: by computing the expectation of the $det^2$ for the i.i.d. exponential variables case (see http://mathoverflow.net/a/13040/31371, though I would do the handling of $Fix$ summation part differently). Then, divide it by $(n(n+1))^n$ that corresponds to the normalization (expectation of $(a_{i1}+\dots+a_{in})^2$ per row), that sends it to the simplex. It provides $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n(n+1))^n}= \frac{(n-1)!}{(n(n+1))^{n-1}}$ for the expectation; perhaps this way is less messy?

Comment: @RichardStanley  Have you published your result?

Comment: @RichardStanley: Would you mind showing your "messy" computation here? Thanks.

Comment: @Hans: The technique is that of Exercise 5.64 in my book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I just checked Exercise 5.64 of your book but have not studied it carefully yet. The matrix there is binary. Are you saying the same technique applies to the current uniform distribution on the simplex?

Answer (score 9):

Hidden in the comment by Victor Kleptsyn is a really nice argument. Since nobody upvoted that comment yet (I just did) it's probably worth expanding it.

From a probabilistic approach it's more natural to show the equivalent statement that the expectation of $(\det A)^2$ equals $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n(n+1))^n}$. The trick is to realize the uniform measure on the simplex as the distribution of
$$ (X_1,\dots,X_n) := \frac{(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)}{Y_1 + \cdots +Y_n} $$
where $(Y_i)$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables (say, of parameter 1). All you need to know is that $\mathbf{E} [Y_i] =1$ and $\mathbf{E} [Y_i^2] =2$. Moreover in this representation $(X_i)$ are independent from $S:=Y_1+\cdots+Y_n$. It follows that we have the following identity in distribution
$$ B = D A $$
where $B$ is a matrix with i.i.d. exponential entries and $D$ a diagonal matrix whose entries are independent copies of $S$, with $A$ and $D$ moreover independent. Therefore
$$ \mathbf{E} [\det B^2] = \mathbf{E} [\det D^2] \cdot \mathbf{E} [\det A^2] .$$
It is very easy to check that $\mathbf{E} [\det D^2] = (n(n+1))^n$, and $\mathbf{E} [\det B^2]$ can be expanded as
$$ \sum_{\sigma,\tau \in \mathfrak{S}_n} \varepsilon(\sigma) \varepsilon(\tau) 
2^{Fix(\sigma \tau^{-1})} = n! \sum_{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n} \varepsilon(\pi)
2^{Fix(\pi)} = n! \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & \ddots & \vdots \\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 1 & \cdots & \cdots & 2 \end{pmatrix} = (n+1)!$$
(Here $Fix$ denotes the number of fixed points.)

Comment: I haven't understood why $(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$ is independent from $S = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n$ ?

Comment: This is because the density of $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ at a point $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ depends only on $y_1+\dots+y_n$. It is similar to the following situation, which is maybe more standard: if $Z=(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables, then $Z/||Z||_2$ is independent from $||Z||_2$ because the density of $Z$ depends only on $\|Z\|_2$ (the standard Euclidean norm).

Comment: Does it imply that since the density of $Z$ depends actually on any strictly monotone function $ g(\left \| Z \right \|_2)$, so the pair of random variables $Z/g(\left \| Z \right \|_2)$ and $g(\left \| Z \right \|_2)$ are independent as well?

Comment: No (If for example $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then $g(||Z||_2)$ is a function of $Z/g(||Z||_2)$). You also need to use the fact that the polar decomposition induces a bijection between $\mathbf{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ and $(0,\infty) \times S^{n-1}$; after passing to polar coordinates the density has a product form, hence independence. In the case of exponential variables, the "polar" decomposition induces a bijection between $(0,\infty)^n$ and $(0,\infty) \times \Delta_{n-1}$ where $\Delta_{n-1}$ is the standard simplex.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a full answer.**

The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is the volume of the parallelotope spanned by its rows. That volume is equal to $n!$ times the volume of the $n$-simplex whose vertices are at the origin and at the vectors which are the rows of $A$.

When those vectors are on the standard $(n-1)$-simplex, we can compute the volume of the $n$-simplex by the formula for the volume of a pyramid: the volume of the base times the height, divided by $n$.

In this case, the base is the $(n-1)$-simplex formed by the rows of $A$, and the height is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Thus the determinant of $A$ is $\frac{n! V}{n\sqrt{n}}$, where $V$ is the volume of the $(n-1)$-simplex spanned by the rows of $A$.

The square of the determinant is $(\det A)^2 = \frac{n!^2 V^2}{n^3}$.

Therefore the average value over all such $A$ of the square of the determinant is $\frac{n!^2}{n^3}E(V^2)$.

"All" that remains is to compute the expected value $E(V^2)$ of the squared volume of a subsimplex of a standard simplex. Note that the analogous question for the expected volume $E(V)$ is apparently quite difficult, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplexSimplexPicking.html